# An attempt was made to set a data set parameter '@Body' that is not defined in this data set. Works on Dev and QA SQL servers, not in User Test?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset

We have three nearly identical SQL environments: Dev, QA and UserTest.  SSRS reports developed in MSVS 2019, shared data sets, in Dev.  Deployed and tested.  Report runs.  Deployment target changed to QA server, deployed and tested.  Report runs.  Deployment target changed to UserTest server, deployed and tested.  Error above generated.  Other reports developed in the same way, deployed the same way, work in all three environments.  SP verified to have parameter, over and over again.
The report's shared dataset recognizes the parameter (From Report Builder):
[image]

And it produces results:

[image]

But running the report in RB (or on the SSRS Server) generates an error:
[image]

Again, remember, this report and nearly a dozen others have been successfully deployed to QA AND UserTest and tested out.  But this report and a couple others similar to it are failing on UserTest

Comment: So here's an update.  I built an entirely new report and duplicated the parameter and dataset functionality using existing SPs and DSs with the exception of the main DS throwing the error.  For that one I created a new one using the same SP.  Copied all the structures from the existing report to the new one.  Deployed the new report.  Ran perfectly.  Changed the DS in the new report to use the existing one that was throwing the error.  Works fine.  Changed the existing report to use the new DS, still errors out.  Microsoft being Microsoft.